# Pass selected row title back to main table view controller

Tags: swift, xcode7

I have a main table view controller with static cells that have a  title and then a detail label. When the user clicks on "cell 1" they are taken to a second table view controller with static cells. They choose from a list ( only one cell can be picked) and then when they hit the back button whatever cells title they picked is transferred into the detail label of the cell they clicked on. The main view controller has outlets to each detail label. I've messed with it for two days and can't seem to get it to work

Comment: What exactly is your question? What have you tried? Let us see some sample code. This is very vague as it is.

Comment: func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) {
    println("You selected cell #\(indexPath.row)!")

    // Get Cell Label
    let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow();
    let currentCell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath!) as UITableViewCell!;
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "YourStoryBoardFileName", bundle: nil)
    var viewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("viewControllerIdentifer") as AnotherViewController
    viewController.passedValue = currentCell.textLabel.text

Comment: I am sorry just started learning swift

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways of solving this problem.

1. Using Delegate

   You just implement a delegate and get the data back from the secondary view controller.
   In the secondary view controller, you can call a delegate like this.

   self.delegate.dataInputed(xxx)

   and the first view controller's dataInputed method will be called. 
   In the dataInputed Method, you can update the value of the data source for the selected indexPath, and reload the Data
2. Send Notification

   You just keep the selected table cell indexPath, and after receiving a notification from the secondary detail view controller, you can update the value of the data source for the selected indexPath, and reload the table.

Comment: I forgot to say I was using an unwind segue also

Comment: hey Harri can you please explain with one example or you can also ping the link for reference. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Add a delegate property that is type of DismissDelegate to your second view controller and set it to the first controller.
Add this protocol

```
protocol DismissDelegate {
     func selectedCell(index : int)
}
```

When the second view is dismissed e.g. in the viewWillDisapper method, call the selectedCell method and pass it the selectedCell

```
delegate.selectedCell(self.tableView.indexOfSelectedCell) //i don't know the correct function
```

Then in the main view controller conform to the protocol and do whatever you need to do with the index

```
func selectedCell(index : int) {
    //whatever you need to do with the index
}
```